# Why does browser encode attributes of an element using html entities instead of escape quote?

Tags: javascript, browser

I noticed that if I do `$('<div>', {"data-json": '{"name":"max"}'})[0].outerHTML`,

I'll get

`<div data-json="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;max&quot;}"></div>`

instead of

`<div data-json="{\"name\":\"max\"}"></div>`

And I've tested on both chrome and firefox.

Is there any particular reason they do one instead of the other?

Because it seems to me that escape quote feels simpler, faster, and more universal when deal with string.

Note: I got the answer from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866

```
    The value of the attribute may be either:

    * A string literal, delimited by single quotes or double
    quotes and not containing any occurrences of the delimiting
    character.

        NOTE - Some historical implementations consider any
        occurrence of the `>' character to signal the end of
        a tag. For compatibility with such implementations,
        when `>' appears in an attribute value, it should be
        represented with a numeric character reference. For
        example, `<IMG SRC="eq1.jpg" alt="a>b">' should be
        written `<IMG SRC="eq1.jpg" alt="a&#62;b">' or `<IMG
        SRC="eq1.jpg" alt="a&gt;b">'.

    * A name token (a sequence of letters, digits, periods, or
    hyphens). Name tokens are not case sensitive.

        NOTE - Some historical implementations allow any
        character except space or `>' in a name token.
```

Comment: Because the `\` has no special meaning in HTML. It's an escape in JavaScript, not in HTML. You're getting back HTML that delivers the attribute value you requested. It may not "feel... more universal", but it actually *works*, which is nice.

Comment: attribs care about html correctness, not JS readability

Comment: while, escape string also provide correctness, and faster at the same time.

Comment: I got the answer from http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1866

Comment: Nothing in the section you quoted says anything about `\\` for escape, which, again, simply *does not work in HTML*. Being wrong about this seems very important to you, so I'm going to back away and let someone else beat their head against this particular wall.

Comment: Really? We are holding a 20 year old spec as gospel? Accept it won't work and move on.

Comment: I think two things are related to why they cannot use '\' for escape. 1. 'and not containing any occurrences of the delimiting character.' 2. for historical reason, they don't allow '>' to appear in the attribute text. And escape string cannot deal with any of these restrictions.

Comment: @patricksweeney, I cannot think of any other reasons. I think if it's not for this, escape quote is definitely better.

Comment: Keep in mind that this issue will only ever come up if you export your attriburte data using outerHtml. The browser's internal document model doesn't encode or decode strings.  And to reiterate what Paul Roub said: backslashes are for excaping Javascript strings. They do NOT work for html.